# how to find nth term of different fibonacci series with golden ratio

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

**what i know :**

if i want to find  $Nth$ term of a fibonacci series like :

```
1   1   2   3   5   8   13  21 .......
```

then to find $6th$ term we use golden ratio like:

[image]

so it becomes like :

[image]

well and good.now

**what i want to know :**

what changes should i make in golden ratio or while applying it for different fibonacci series . For example :

```
1   6   7   13   20   33 .......
```

now if i want to find the 10th no. of above series then what changes should i do in golden ratio... now what is the value of **X<sub>10</sub>**'s R.H.S(right hand side)

**X<sub>10</sub> = ?** (for this fibonacci series)

Comment: If you look at a derivation of Binet's formula using generating functions, then it should be clear how to generalize the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the solution of a recursion $a_n = A a_{n-1} + B a_{n-2}$ is of the form $a_n = C \lambda_1^n + D \lambda_2^n$, where $\lambda_{1,2}$ are the roots of $\lambda^2 - A \lambda - B  = 0$. You can find $C$ and $D$ by plugging in $n=0$ and $n=1$.

For the Fibonacci sequence, one of $\lambda_{1,2}$ is equal to the golden ratio.

Comment: cant get you,sorry ..can you explain with the example please

Comment: In your example, $A=B=1$ so the roots of the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2 + \lambda + 1=0$ again equal the golden ratio $\phi$ and $1-\phi$. Hence the general term is $a_n = C \phi^n + D(1-\phi)^n$, where $C$ and $D$ can be determined from $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: for the next one a=6 and b=7 right???

Comment: according to your solution it should be λ^2 - λ - 1 = 0 but you wrote λ^2 + λ + 1 = 0  ... why???

Comment: You're right, should be $\lambda^2=\lambda+1$.

Comment: how will i get **C** and **D** from a0 and a1

Comment: Solve the system $C+D=a_0$, $C\phi + D(1-\phi) = a_1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $s$ satisfies the recurrence $s_{n+2} = s_n + s_{n+1}$, and its first two terms are $s_0$ and $s_1$, then
then $$s_i = s_0f_{i-1} + s_1f_i$$ for all $i$, where $f_n = 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, \ldots$ is the Fibonacci sequence.

For example, the sequence $a_i = 1,   6,   7,   13,   20,   33,\ldots $ is generated by $a_i = f_{i-1} + 6f_i$:

$$\begin{array}{r|rr|r}
i & f_{i-1} & f_i & f_{i-1} + 6f_i \\\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 6 \\
2 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\
3 & 1 & 2 & 13 \\
4 & 2 & 3 & 20 \\
5 & 3 & 5 & 33 \\
6 & 5 & 8 & 53 \\
\end{array}$$

You already have a formula for $f_i$, which you can substitute into $f_{i-1} + 6f_i$ to get a formula for your sequence.